# Xcode UI Test: simulator not visible while test running

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, xcode-ui-testing

I'm running into an issue when running UITests in Xcode the simulator is launched but not visible, the tests still run fine, but I can't see what's happening.

[image: Simulator Launched]

I believe the test is running because I can see all the output, and if I make something wrong on purpose, the debug output correctly shows it as well. If I run the main target, or unit test target, the simulator is visible, the problem is only with UI tests.

I tried to clean the project, remove derived data, and even restarted the machine but no help.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @PaulT. I posted an answer below, it fixed my issue, not sure if it's also the case for you.

Answer (score 5):

There is a dedicated option in Simulator Menu under Debug tab
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by disabling parallel testing in Edit Scheme -> Tests -> *UITest -> Options.